# Modificar lado de crecimiento `width` con `transition` dependiendo de la cercanía al borde derecho de la pantalla `css3`

Tags: html, css3

Genero las listas con `css3` de esta manera:

```css
.list-contenedor {
  max-width: 400px;
  min-width: 150px;
  height: 50px;
  position: unset;
  font-size: 10pt;
}

.list-maquina {
  position: relative;
  width: 150px;
}
.list-orden-grupo {
  position: relative;
  width: 150px;
  max-width: 600;
    direction: ltr;

  transition: all 300ms ease-out 100ms;
}

.list-orden-grupo:hover {
  width: 400px;
  z-index: 200;
}

.list-orden-grupo .list-orden {
  height: 1px;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
}

.list-orden-grupo:hover .list-orden {
  animation: 0.5s in;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes in {
  0% {
    height: 1px;
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  1% {
    position: static;
    visibility: visible;
  }
  100% {
    position: static;
    opacity: 1;
    height: 50px;
  }
}


.list-orden-grupo:hover .active {
    transition: all 300ms ease-out 100ms;

}
.list-orden-grupo:hover .active {
    background-color: rgb(16, 42, 119);
    
}
.list-orden-grupo .list-orden-en-cola {
    display: none;
    
}
.list-orden-grupo:hover .list-orden-en-cola {
    display: inline;
    
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-12 d-flex justify-content-center">
    <div class="row">
      <div
        class="list-contenedor shadow mr-3 mb-2"
        *ngFor="let maquina of maquinas"
      >
        <ul class="list-group list-maquina mt-2">
          <span
            [id]="maquina._id"
            cdkDropList
            (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)"
            [cdkDropListData]="maquina.pila"
            [cdkDropListConnectedTo]="idsMaquinas()"
            class="list-orden-grupo"
          >
            <li class="list-group-item active text-center shadow rounded">
              <span
                class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center w-100 "
              >
                <span> maquina</span>
                <span>
                  | <i class="fas fa-cog    "></i>
                  <span class="list-orden-en-cola">
                    En cola:
                  </span>
                  0</span
                >
              </span>
            </li>

            <li class="list-group-item list-orden shadow list-group-item-dark">
              <ng-container *ngIf="maquina.trabajando; else sinTrabajoTemp">
                <i class="fas fa-cog   fa-spin text-warning"></i>
                {{ maquina.trabajo }}
              </ng-container>
              <ng-template #sinTrabajoTemp>
                Sin trabajo asignado
              </ng-template>
            </li>

            <li
              *ngIf="maquina.pila.length"
              class="list-group-item list-orden shadow d-flex justify-content-between"
            >
              <b> 
              
                <i 
                (click)="reiniciarPila(maquina)"
                class="fas fa-recycle text-danger   "></i>

              </b>
              <b
                title="Click para ordenar por este campo"
                (click)="ordenarPila(maquina, 'numeroDeOrden')"
              >
                #ORD
              </b>
              <b
                title="Click para ordenar por este campo"
                (click)="ordenarPila(maquina, 'modeloCompleto')"
              >
                MOD
              </b>
              <b
                title="Click para ordenar por este campo"
                (click)="ordenarPila(maquina, 'paso')"
              >
                PASO
              </b>
            </li>
            <li
              cdkDrag
              *ngFor="let orden of maquina.pila; let i = index"
              class="list-group-item list-orden shadow d-flex justify-content-between"
            >
              <span class="no-wrap text-left"># 20.-</span>
              <span class="no-wrap text-left">2-20-2</span>
              <span class=" text-left">25651554</span>
              <span class="no-wrap text-left">21521</span>
            </li>
            <li
              *ngIf="!maquina.pila.length"
              class="list-group-item list-orden shadow"
            >
              No hay ordenes asignadas
            </li>
          </span>
        </ul>
      </div>
      
      
      
      
      
      
      
      <div
        class="list-contenedor shadow mr-3 mb-2"
        *ngFor="let maquina of maquinas"
      >
        <ul class="list-group list-maquina mt-2">
          <span
            [id]="maquina._id"
            cdkDropList
            (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)"
            [cdkDropListData]="maquina.pila"
            [cdkDropListConnectedTo]="idsMaquinas()"
            class="list-orden-grupo"
          >
            <li class="list-group-item active text-center shadow rounded">
              <span
                class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center w-100 "
              >
                <span> maquina</span>
                <span>
                  | <i class="fas fa-cog    "></i>
                  <span class="list-orden-en-cola">
                    En cola:
                  </span>
                  0</span
                >
              </span>
            </li>

            <li class="list-group-item list-orden shadow list-group-item-dark">
              <ng-container *ngIf="maquina.trabajando; else sinTrabajoTemp">
                <i class="fas fa-cog   fa-spin text-warning"></i>
                {{ maquina.trabajo }}
              </ng-container>
              <ng-template #sinTrabajoTemp>
                Sin trabajo asignado
              </ng-template>
            </li>

            <li
              *ngIf="maquina.pila.length"
              class="list-group-item list-orden shadow d-flex justify-content-between"
            >
              <b> 
              
                <i 
                (click)="reiniciarPila(maquina)"
                class="fas fa-recycle text-danger   "></i>

              </b>
              <b
                title="Click para ordenar por este campo"
                (click)="ordenarPila(maquina, 'numeroDeOrden')"
              >
                #ORD
              </b>
              <b
                title="Click para ordenar por este campo"
                (click)="ordenarPila(maquina, 'modeloCompleto')"
              >
                MOD
              </b>
              <b
                title="Click para ordenar por este campo"
                (click)="ordenarPila(maquina, 'paso')"
              >
                PASO
              </b>
            </li>
            <li
              cdkDrag
              *ngFor="let orden of maquina.pila; let i = index"
              class="list-group-item list-orden shadow d-flex justify-content-between"
            >
              <span class="no-wrap text-left"># 20.-</span>
              <span class="no-wrap text-left">2-20-2</span>
              <span class=" text-left">25651554</span>
              <span class="no-wrap text-left">21521</span>
            </li>
            <li
              *ngIf="!maquina.pila.length"
              class="list-group-item list-orden shadow"
            >
              No hay ordenes asignadas
            </li>
          </span>
        </ul>
      </div>
      
      
      
      
      
      
      
      
      <div
        class="list-contenedor shadow mr-3 mb-2"
        *ngFor="let maquina of maquinas"
      >
        <ul class="list-group list-maquina mt-2">
          <span
            [id]="maquina._id"
            cdkDropList
            (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)"
            [cdkDropListData]="maquina.pila"
            [cdkDropListConnectedTo]="idsMaquinas()"
            class="list-orden-grupo"
          >
            <li class="list-group-item active text-center shadow rounded">
              <span
                class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center w-100 "
              >
                <span> maquina</span>
                <span>
                  | <i class="fas fa-cog    "></i>
                  <span class="list-orden-en-cola">
                    En cola:
                  </span>
                  0</span
                >
              </span>
            </li>

            <li class="list-group-item list-orden shadow list-group-item-dark">
              <ng-container *ngIf="maquina.trabajando; else sinTrabajoTemp">
                <i class="fas fa-cog   fa-spin text-warning"></i>
                {{ maquina.trabajo }}
              </ng-container>
              <ng-template #sinTrabajoTemp>
                Sin trabajo asignado
              </ng-template>
            </li>

            <li
              *ngIf="maquina.pila.length"
              class="list-group-item list-orden shadow d-flex justify-content-between"
            >
              <b> 
              
                <i 
                (click)="reiniciarPila(maquina)"
                class="fas fa-recycle text-danger   "></i>

              </b>
              <b
                title="Click para ordenar por este campo"
                (click)="ordenarPila(maquina, 'numeroDeOrden')"
              >
                #ORD
              </b>
              <b
                title="Click para ordenar por este campo"
                (click)="ordenarPila(maquina, 'modeloCompleto')"
              >
                MOD
              </b>
              <b
                title="Click para ordenar por este campo"
                (click)="ordenarPila(maquina, 'paso')"
              >
                PASO
              </b>
            </li>
            <li
              cdkDrag
              *ngFor="let orden of maquina.pila; let i = index"
              class="list-group-item list-orden shadow d-flex justify-content-between"
            >
              <span class="no-wrap text-left"># 20.-</span>
              <span class="no-wrap text-left">2-20-2</span>
              <span class=" text-left">25651554</span>
              <span class="no-wrap text-left">21521</span>
            </li>
            <li
              *ngIf="!maquina.pila.length"
              class="list-group-item list-orden shadow"
            >
              No hay ordenes asignadas
            </li>
          </span>
        </ul>
      </div>
      
      
      
      
      
      
      
      <div
        class="list-contenedor shadow mr-3 mb-2"
        *ngFor="let maquina of maquinas"
      >
        <ul class="list-group list-maquina mt-2">
          <span
            [id]="maquina._id"
            cdkDropList
            (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)"
            [cdkDropListData]="maquina.pila"
            [cdkDropListConnectedTo]="idsMaquinas()"
            class="list-orden-grupo"
          >
            <li class="list-group-item active text-center shadow rounded">
              <span
                class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center w-100 "
              >
                <span> maquina</span>
                <span>
                  | <i class="fas fa-cog    "></i>
                  <span class="list-orden-en-cola">
                    En cola:
                  </span>
                  0</span
                >
              </span>
            </li>

            <li class="list-group-item list-orden shadow list-group-item-dark">
              <ng-container *ngIf="maquina.trabajando; else sinTrabajoTemp">
                <i class="fas fa-cog   fa-spin text-warning"></i>
                {{ maquina.trabajo }}
              </ng-container>
              <ng-template #sinTrabajoTemp>
                Sin trabajo asignado
              </ng-template>
            </li>

            <li
              *ngIf="maquina.pila.length"
              class="list-group-item list-orden shadow d-flex justify-content-between"
            >
              <b> 
              
                <i 
                (click)="reiniciarPila(maquina)"
                class="fas fa-recycle text-danger   "></i>

              </b>
              <b
                title="Click para ordenar por este campo"
                (click)="ordenarPila(maquina, 'numeroDeOrden')"
              >
                #ORD
              </b>
              <b
                title="Click para ordenar por este campo"
                (click)="ordenarPila(maquina, 'modeloCompleto')"
              >
                MOD
              </b>
              <b
                title="Click para ordenar por este campo"
                (click)="ordenarPila(maquina, 'paso')"
              >
                PASO
              </b>
            </li>
            <li
              cdkDrag
              *ngFor="let orden of maquina.pila; let i = index"
              class="list-group-item list-orden shadow d-flex justify-content-between"
            >
              <span class="no-wrap text-left"># 20.-</span>
              <span class="no-wrap text-left">2-20-2</span>
              <span class=" text-left">25651554</span>
              <span class="no-wrap text-left">21521</span>
            </li>
            <li
              *ngIf="!maquina.pila.length"
              class="list-group-item list-orden shadow"
            >
              No hay ordenes asignadas
            </li>
          </span>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Estoy intentando que los elementos mas hacia la derecha crezcan hacia la izquierda y no se pierda su contenido al salir de la pantalla. Es posible hacer esto solo con `css3`?

Comportamiento que quiero prevenir:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La flecha señala el lado hacia el que quiero que crezca el contenido. La x esta fuera de la ventana y como se ve en la imagen se recorta el contenido. Esto es lo que quiero prevenir.

## Informacion

Las listas se generan dinámicamente. La cantidad que se genera puede ser impar y deben, en la medida de lo posible ser responsivas. Así que actualmente se acomodan al tamaño de la ventana. 4x4x2, 3x3x3x1, etc.

Comment: No podrías resumir un poco mas el código?

Comment: Repetí algunas partes para que se mostraran varias listas.

Comment: Hola @Angel ¿No te importaría si la respuesta tuviera un código algo diferente para lograr su simplificación pero con el mismo resultado? Es decir, la cantidad mínima y después lo incorporas en tu proyecto. Una vez en tu proyecto, lo adaptas para que sea compatible con él.

Comment: Con el mismo resultado, me refiere a lo que deseas que haga.

Comment: una imagen vale mas que mil palabras

Comment: @DavidE.LunaM. El código de ejemplo se comporta como el de producción. La condición es que crezca hacia el lado opuesto de la pantalla manteniendo la funcionalidades actuales. (Que ya se muestran)

Comment: @Srsole No entiendo tu comentario.

Comment: Pues que podiras currarte un ejemplo grafico-

Comment: No entiendo muy bien qué es lo que quieres lograr. Según tu código actual, ¿cuál es la falla? ¿Qué es lo que no debería pasar, o lo que no está pasando? Te recomiendo que nos compartas una imagen de lo que deseas, así más usuarios podemos ayudarte a encontrar una solución

Comment: @Srsole Currado.

Comment: @JheymanMejia Listo.

Comment: Existe la posibilidad de usar JS?

Comment: @Srsole Si, pero si hay respuesta posible solo con `css3` voy a dar preferencia a estas.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Agregando la siguiente regla `CSS`, obtenemos el resultado que pides.

```
.list-contenedor:nth-of-type(3n) .list-orden-grupo,
.list-contenedor:nth-of-type(4n) .list-orden-grupo {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
}
```

Al asignarles `right: 0;` se consigue que no crezcan a la derecha.

Para hacer que este comportamiento solo suceda en determinados tamaños de pantalla, puedes utilizar [*Media Query*](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp), y especificar este comportamiento solo para determinados tamaños.

```
/* Solo en pantallas menores de 600px*/
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .list-contenedor:nth-of-type(3n) .list-orden-grupo,
  .list-contenedor:nth-of-type(4n) .list-orden-grupo {
      position: absolute;
      right: 0;
  }
}
```

A continuación muestro un ejemplo (También disponible en [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d9yq2Lc4/2/)) donde se abren los dos últimos elementos hacia la izquierda. Puedes especificar los elementos cambiando el selector de [`.list-contenedor:nth-of-type()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type).

```js
const elements_to_right = 2; // Numero de elementos (mas a la derecha) a aplicar la clase

function setRightClass() {
  // Comprobamos cada elemento
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.getElementsByClassName('list-contenedor'), function (el) {
    var el_right = el.getBoundingClientRect().right; // Derecha elemento
    var el_width = el.getBoundingClientRect().width; // Tamaño elemento
    var el_r_margin = parseInt(getComputedStyle(el).marginRight.slice(0,-2)); // Obtener margen derecho

    el.classList.remove("right-element"); // Quitamos la clase, por si se a echo un resize
    // Si no cave otro elemento (la suma de su posicion, con el tamaño y el margen) * los elementos que quramos, se agrega la clase
    if (el_right + (el_width + el_r_margin) * elements_to_right >= window.innerWidth) {
      el.classList.add("right-element"); // Agregar clase
    }
  });
}

(function() {
  // Llamar la función cada vez que se redimensione la pantalla
  window.addEventListener("resize", setRightClass);
  
  // Llamar por primera vez a la función
  setRightClass(1);
})();
```

```css
.list-contenedor {
    max-width: 400px;
    min-width: 150px;
    height: 50px;
    position: unset;
    font-size: 10pt;
}

.list-maquina {
    position: relative;
    width: 150px;
}

.list-orden-grupo {
    width: 150px;
    max-width: 600;
    direction: ltr;
    transition: all 300ms ease-out 100ms;
}

.list-orden-grupo:hover {
    width: 400px;
    z-index: 200;
}

.list-orden-grupo .list-orden {
    height: 1px;
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
}

.list-orden-grupo:hover .list-orden {
    animation: 0.5s in;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes in {
    0% {
        height: 1px;
        position: absolute;
        opacity: 0;
    }
    1% {
        position: static;
        visibility: visible;
    }
    100% {
        position: static;
        opacity: 1;
        height: 50px;
    }
}

.list-orden-grupo:hover .active {
    transition: all 300ms ease-out 100ms;
}

.list-orden-grupo:hover .active {
    background-color: rgb(16, 42, 119);
}

.list-orden-grupo .list-orden-en-cola {
    display: none;
}

.list-orden-grupo:hover .list-orden-en-cola {
    display: inline;
}

.list-contenedor {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/*Abrir a la izquierda*/
.list-contenedor.right-element .list-orden-grupo {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-12 d-flex justify-content-center">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="list-contenedor shadow mr-3 mb-2" *ngfor="let maquina of maquinas">
        <ul class="list-group list-maquina mt-2">
          <span [id]="maquina._id" cdkdroplist="" (cdkdroplistdropped)="drop($event)" [cdkdroplistdata]="maquina.pila" [cdkdroplistconnectedto]="idsMaquinas()" class="list-orden-grupo">
            <li class="list-group-item active text-center shadow rounded">
              <span class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center w-100 ">
                <span> maquina</span>
                <span>
                  | <i class="fas fa-cog    "></i>
                  <span class="list-orden-en-cola">
                    En cola:
                  </span>
                  0</span>
              </span>
            </li>

            <li class="list-group-item list-orden shadow list-group-item-dark">
              <ng-container *ngif="maquina.trabajando; else sinTrabajoTemp">
                <i class="fas fa-cog   fa-spin text-warning"></i>
                {{ maquina.trabajo }}
              </ng-container>
              <ng-template #sintrabajotemp="">
                Sin trabajo asignado
              </ng-template>
            </li>

            <li *ngif="maquina.pila.length" class="list-group-item list-orden shadow d-flex justify-content-between">
              <b> 
              
                <i (click)="reiniciarPila(maquina)" class="fas fa-recycle text-danger   "></i>

              </b>
              <b title="Click para ordenar por este campo" (click)="ordenarPila(maquina, 'numeroDeOrden')">
                #ORD
              </b>
              <b title="Click para ordenar por este campo" (click)="ordenarPila(maquina, 'modeloCompleto')">
                MOD
              </b>
              <b title="Click para ordenar por este campo" (click)="ordenarPila(maquina, 'paso')">
                PASO
              </b>
            </li>
            <li cdkdrag="" *ngfor="let orden of maquina.pila; let i = index" class="list-group-item list-orden shadow d-flex justify-content-between">
              <span class="no-wrap text-left"># 20.-</span>
              <span class="no-wrap text-left">2-20-2</span>
              <span class=" text-left">25651554</span>
              <span class="no-wrap text-left">21521</span>
            </li>
            <li *ngif="!maquina.pila.length" class="list-group-item list-orden shadow">
              No hay ordenes asignadas
            </li>
          </span>
        </ul>
      </div>
      
      
      
      
      
      
      
      <div class="list-contenedor shadow mr-3 mb-2" *ngfor="let maquina of maquinas">
        <ul class="list-group list-maquina mt-2">
          <span [id]="maquina._id" cdkdroplist="" (cdkdroplistdropped)="drop($event)" [cdkdroplistdata]="maquina.pila" [cdkdroplistconnectedto]="idsMaquinas()" class="list-orden-grupo">
            <li class="list-group-item active text-center shadow rounded">
              <span class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center w-100 ">
                <span> maquina</span>
                <span>
                  | <i class="fas fa-cog    "></i>
                  <span class="list-orden-en-cola">
                    En cola:
                  </span>
                  0</span>
              </span>
            </li>

            <li class="list-group-item list-orden shadow list-group-item-dark">
              <ng-container *ngif="maquina.trabajando; else sinTrabajoTemp">
                <i class="fas fa-cog   fa-spin text-warning"></i>
                {{ maquina.trabajo }}
              </ng-container>
              <ng-template #sintrabajotemp="">
                Sin trabajo asignado
              </ng-template>
            </li>

            <li *ngif="maquina.pila.length" class="list-group-item list-orden shadow d-flex justify-content-between">
              <b> 
              
                <i (click)="reiniciarPila(maquina)" class="fas fa-recycle text-danger   "></i>

              </b>
              <b title="Click para ordenar por este campo" (click)="ordenarPila(maquina, 'numeroDeOrden')">
                #ORD
              </b>
              <b title="Click para ordenar por este campo" (click)="ordenarPila(maquina, 'modeloCompleto')">
                MOD
              </b>
              <b title="Click para ordenar por este campo" (click)="ordenarPila(maquina, 'paso')">
                PASO
              </b>
            </li>
            <li cdkdrag="" *ngfor="let orden of maquina.pila; let i = index" class="list-group-item list-orden shadow d-flex justify-content-between">
              <span class="no-wrap text-left"># 20.-</span>
              <span class="no-wrap text-left">2-20-2</span>
              <span class=" text-left">25651554</span>
              <span class="no-wrap text-left">21521</span>
            </li>
            <li *ngif="!maquina.pila.length" class="list-group-item list-orden shadow">
              No hay ordenes asignadas
            </li>
          </span>
        </ul>
      </div>
      
      
      
      
      
      
      
      
      <div class="list-contenedor shadow mr-3 mb-2" *ngfor="let maquina of maquinas">
        <ul class="list-group list-maquina mt-2">
          <span [id]="maquina._id" cdkdroplist="" (cdkdroplistdropped)="drop($event)" [cdkdroplistdata]="maquina.pila" [cdkdroplistconnectedto]="idsMaquinas()" class="list-orden-grupo">
            <li class="list-group-item active text-center shadow rounded">
              <span class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center w-100 ">
                <span> maquina</span>
                <span>
                  | <i class="fas fa-cog    "></i>
                  <span class="list-orden-en-cola">
                    En cola:
                  </span>
                  0</span>
              </span>
            </li>

            <li class="list-group-item list-orden shadow list-group-item-dark">
              <ng-container *ngif="maquina.trabajando; else sinTrabajoTemp">
                <i class="fas fa-cog   fa-spin text-warning"></i>
                {{ maquina.trabajo }}
              </ng-container>
              <ng-template #sintrabajotemp="">
                Sin trabajo asignado
              </ng-template>
            </li>

            <li *ngif="maquina.pila.length" class="list-group-item list-orden shadow d-flex justify-content-between">
              <b> 
              
                <i (click)="reiniciarPila(maquina)" class="fas fa-recycle text-danger   "></i>

              </b>
              <b title="Click para ordenar por este campo" (click)="ordenarPila(maquina, 'numeroDeOrden')">
                #ORD
              </b>
              <b title="Click para ordenar por este campo" (click)="ordenarPila(maquina, 'modeloCompleto')">
                MOD
              </b>
              <b title="Click para ordenar por este campo" (click)="ordenarPila(maquina, 'paso')">
                PASO
              </b>
            </li>
            <li cdkdrag="" *ngfor="let orden of maquina.pila; let i = index" class="list-group-item list-orden shadow d-flex justify-content-between">
              <span class="no-wrap text-left"># 20.-</span>
              <span class="no-wrap text-left">2-20-2</span>
              <span class=" text-left">25651554</span>
              <span class="no-wrap text-left">21521</span>
            </li>
            <li *ngif="!maquina.pila.length" class="list-group-item list-orden shadow">
              No hay ordenes asignadas
            </li>
          </span>
        </ul>
      </div>
      
      
      
      
      
      
      
      <div class="list-contenedor shadow mr-3 mb-2" *ngfor="let maquina of maquinas">
        <ul class="list-group list-maquina mt-2">
          <span [id]="maquina._id" cdkdroplist="" (cdkdroplistdropped)="drop($event)" [cdkdroplistdata]="maquina.pila" [cdkdroplistconnectedto]="idsMaquinas()" class="list-orden-grupo">
            <li class="list-group-item active text-center shadow rounded">
              <span class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center w-100 ">
                <span> maquina</span>
                <span>
                  | <i class="fas fa-cog    "></i>
                  <span class="list-orden-en-cola">
                    En cola:
                  </span>
                  0</span>
              </span>
            </li>

            <li class="list-group-item list-orden shadow list-group-item-dark">
              <ng-container *ngif="maquina.trabajando; else sinTrabajoTemp">
                <i class="fas fa-cog   fa-spin text-warning"></i>
                {{ maquina.trabajo }}
              </ng-container>
              <ng-template #sintrabajotemp="">
                Sin trabajo asignado
              </ng-template>
            </li>

            <li *ngif="maquina.pila.length" class="list-group-item list-orden shadow d-flex justify-content-between">
              <b> 
              
                <i (click)="reiniciarPila(maquina)" class="fas fa-recycle text-danger   "></i>

              </b>
              <b title="Click para ordenar por este campo" (click)="ordenarPila(maquina, 'numeroDeOrden')">
                #ORD
              </b>
              <b title="Click para ordenar por este campo" (click)="ordenarPila(maquina, 'modeloCompleto')">
                MOD
              </b>
              <b title="Click para ordenar por este campo" (click)="ordenarPila(maquina, 'paso')">
                PASO
              </b>
            </li>
            <li cdkdrag="" *ngfor="let orden of maquina.pila; let i = index" class="list-group-item list-orden shadow d-flex justify-content-between">
              <span class="no-wrap text-left"># 20.-</span>
              <span class="no-wrap text-left">2-20-2</span>
              <span class=" text-left">25651554</span>
              <span class="no-wrap text-left">21521</span>
            </li>
            <li *ngif="!maquina.pila.length" class="list-group-item list-orden shadow">
              No hay ordenes asignadas
            </li>
          </span>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**EDITADO**: Ahora se utiliza [`:nth-last-of-type()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-last-of-type), con lo que se aplica a listas dinámicas (último y anteúltimo elemento).

```
/**último elemetno*/
.list-contenedor:nth-last-of-type(1) .list-orden-grupo, 
/*anteúltimo elemetno*/
.list-contenedor:nth-last-of-type(2) .list-orden-grupo { 
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
}
```

El numero corresponde a la posición empezando por detrás, donde 1 es el último, 2 el anteúltimo, y así sucesivamente.

**EDITADO**: Ahora se aplica la clase `right-element` a los elementos que queramos abrir a la izquierda (se a actualizado el ejemplo y tambien en [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dagvjot7/)).

Al cargar, y al re-dimensional la ventana, se calcula que elementos han de tener la clase `right-element`

**JavaScript extra**

```
const elements_to_right = 2; // Numero de elementos (mas a la derecha) a aplicar la clase

function setRightClass() {
  // Comprobamos cada elemento
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.getElementsByClassName('list-contenedor'), function (el) {
    var el_right = el.getBoundingClientRect().right; // Derecha elemento
    var el_width = el.getBoundingClientRect().width; // Tamaño elemento
    var el_r_margin = parseInt(getComputedStyle(el).marginRight.slice(0,-2)); // Obtener margen derecho

    el.classList.remove("right-element"); // Quitamos la clase, por si se a echo un resize
    // Si no cave otro elemento (la suma de su posicion, con el tamaño y el margen) * los elementos que quramos, se agrega la clase
    if (el_right + (el_width + el_r_margin) * elements_to_right >= window.innerWidth) {
      el.classList.add("right-element"); // Agregar clase
    }
  });
}

(function() {
  // Llamar la función cada vez que se redimensione la pantalla
  window.addEventListener("resize", setRightClass);

  // Llamar por primera vez a la función
  setRightClass(1);
})();
```

**CSS extra**

```
/*Abrir a la izquierda*/
.list-contenedor.right-element .list-orden-grupo {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}
```

Puedes cambiar el numero de elementos al que se les aplica la clase modificando el valor de `elements_to_right`.

A partir de aquí, puedes personalizarlo de muchas maneras, ya que ahora dispones de la clase `right-element` en los elementos a la derecha.

Comment: Bueno, encontre un problema. El selector que estas usando solo aplica al 3er y 4to elementos por lo que veo. Pero la lista es dinámica y me encontraré con más elementos. Funcionara igual para 6 elementos o 13?

Comment: Si, de todas formas, solo se ha de cambiar el selector CSS, puedes usar `:last-of-type`, o incluso aplicar una clase dinámicamente a los últimos elementos.

Comment: Esto le quita lo responsivo por que, si genero 10, solo el 9 y 10 tienen esta característica, pero en pantalla el acomodo, por ejemplo podría ser 4x4x2. Así que  tendría que buscar que en cada hilera el último elemento sea el último de un subgrupo(valga la redundancia). Hasta ahora me gusta la respuesta, pero creo que le falta un poco más para llegar a mi objetivo completo.

Comment: Es posible una solución sin javascript?

Comment: Con media [Media Queries](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp), pero tendrias que calcular manualmente cuantos elementos caven en la pantalla, como en este [ejemplo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31789425/css-select-first-div-of-every-line/31789696#31789696).

Answer (score 1):

Existen varias alternativas, veo que usas Bootstrap, por tanto podrías saber que cajas quedan a la izquierda y que a la derecha por el grid que uses y según el tamaño de la pantalla, también puedes puedes agregar clases que distingan las que están a la izquierda y cuales a la derecha, puedes usar:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#order-classes para ordenar también y con css se puede agregar a .list-orden-group un right según su distancia a la derecha o a la izquierda, pero esta distancia sólo la puedes saber por javascript.

Javascript que podría solucionar el problema:
Obtienes la lista de elementos

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("list-orden-grupo")
```

Por cada uno calculas la distancia al borde derecho y en el caso de ser menor al ancho de un elemento más un margen le agregamos una clase y gestionas por css

```
var widthView = document.body.clientWidth
for (var e of elements) {
    var elementWidth = e.getBoundingClientRect().width
    var elementLeft = e.getBoundingClientRect().left
    var distanceElementToRight = widthView - (elementLeft + elementWidth)
    if (distanceElementToRight < elementWidth + 100) {
         e.classList.add("openleft");
    }
}
```

y estilo

```
 .list-orden-grupo {
        right:...
    }
```

A ver si te sirve.

Comment: Puedes hacer un ejemplo funcional de esto?

Comment: gracias por tu contribución, recuerda revisar [answer] para conocer como realizar las respuestas en el sitio, saludos!